Get current liquidity and token reserves, Error: missing revert data, ethers 6.12.0
I'm trying to create a node.js software which, on the polygon network, on uniswap v3, increasing the liquidity for a position for the wbtc/matic pair (pool id 1597116, fee 0.05%), calculates how many matics are needed.
I created a polygon wallet with around $30, I opened a position (https://app.uniswap.org/pools/1597116) to provide liquidity to uniswap, wbtc/matic pair, fee 0.05%.
I created this little program with the help of claude3.
My expectation: Know how many matics are needed to increase the position by 0.0002 wbtc
ethers  6.12.0
        const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider  } = require('ethers');
    const infuraKey = '...';
    const walletAddress = '...';
    const privateKey = '...';
    const INFURA_URL = `https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`;
    const { abi: IUniswapV3PoolABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json');
    const { abi: INonfungiblePositionManagerABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol/INonfungiblePositionManager.json');
    const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(INFURA_URL)
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    const poolAddress = '0x1BFD67037B42Cf73acF2047067bd4F2C47D9BfD6';
    const positionManagerAddress = '0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88';
    const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);
    const positionManagerContract = new ethers.Contract(positionManagerAddress, INonfungiblePositionManagerABI, wallet);

    async function main() {
        console.log("ethers.version: ",ethers.version);
        const tokenId = 1597116;
        const wbtcAmount = ethers.parseUnits('0.0002', 8); // WBTC amount to be added
        // Get current liquidity and token reserves
        const [liquidity, , , token0Reserve, token1Reserve] = await Promise.all([
            positionManagerContract.positions(tokenId),
            poolContract.slot0(),
            poolContract.token0(),
            poolContract.token1(),
        ]);

        // Calculate the amount of MATIC needed to increase liquidity 
        const token0Amount = wbtcAmount;
        const token1Amount = await poolContract.quote(token0Amount, token0Reserve, token1Reserve);

        console.log(`To increase liquidity by 1 WBTC, you need ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(token1Amount, 18)} MATIC`);


    }

    main().catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

i got this error:
Error: missing revert data (action="call", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x3850c7bd", "to": "[...]" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.12.0)
at makeError (C:\nodejs\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:129:21)
at getBuiltinCallException (C:\nodejs\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\abi-coder.js:105:37)
at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (C:\nodejs\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\abi-coder.js:206:16)
at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (C:\nodejs\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:668:43)
at C:\nodejs\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
action: 'call',
data: null,
reason: null,
transaction: {
to: '[...]',
data: '0x3850c7bd'
},
invocation: null,
revert: null,
shortMessage: 'missing revert data',
info: {
error: { code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted' },
payload: { method: 'eth_call', params: [Array], id: 2, jsonrpc: '2.0' }
}
}

your codes not going to work you just quoted a swap.    You already have liquidity in the pool so quoting a swap wont give you the answer, also quoting a swap will move the current price when you quote.    While adding liquidity does move the spot price at all it just makes it harder to move.

All you really need to do is calculate it from the spot price
